# Error: elasticsearch has no deployed releases Error: plugin "2to3" exited with error

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, helm3

I am running `helm3 2to3 convert --dry-run elasticsearch`, but running into an issue. Any idea what could be the issue?

```text
2021/08/18 15:52:41 NOTE: This is in dry-run mode, the following actions will not be executed.
2021/08/18 15:52:41 Run without --dry-run to take the actions described below:
2021/08/18 15:52:41
2021/08/18 15:52:41 Release "elasticsearch" will be converted from Helm v2 to Helm v3.
2021/08/18 15:52:41 [Helm 3] Release "elasticsearch" will be created.
Error: elasticsearch has no deployed releases
Error: plugin "2to3" exited with error
```

Comment: Does `elasticsearch` show up when you do `helm ls`?

Comment: Elastic search is listed fro that command.

Comment: Is it in a deployed state?

Comment: Yes it is in deployed state.